# Loop for cell comparison in IF-THEN statement

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare each cell from range `src.Range("A1:A" & 10)` with cells in range `src3.Range("A1:A" & 3)` and proceed only if `src` cell is not equal to any of `src3` cells. It works if I manually list each comparison (as comment - what I have to get eventually. It works but there will be much greater range for comparison). But it does not when I try to loop it. I cannot separate`IF` from `THEN`. And I cannot find alternative.

```
  For temprow = 1 To rngSelectionTable.Rows.Count                         
    tempselected = rngSelectionTable(temprow, 2).Value                      
    Crit = rngSelectionTable(temprow, 5).Value                              

    If tempselected = True Then

    For Each r In src.Range("A1:A" & 10)                

         'If r <> 0 _
          And r <> src3.Range("A1") _
          And r <> src3.Range("A2") _
          And r <> src3.Range("A3") _
          Then myFinalResult = r

        For Each comparisonRange In src3.Range("A1:A" & 3) 'does not work
          If r <> 0 And r <> comparisonRange 'does not work
              Next comparisonRange 'does not work
          Then myFinalResult = r 'does not work

        'rest of the code below
             If myFinalResult = Crit Then                                 
                 If CopyRange Is Nothing Then                        
                     Set CopyRange = r.EntireRow                 
                           Else
                     Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, r.EntireRow) 
                 End If
             End If   
       Next r
    End If
  Next temprow
```

Comment: Could you post the whole procedure or function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, rng10 As Range, rng3 As Range
    Set rng10 = Sheet1.Range("a1:a10")
    Set rng3 = Sheet2.Range("$a$1:$a$3")

    For Each r In rng10
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng3, r) > 0 Then
            'proceed here
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: hm, does not work for me... I simplified it just for one `r = 1` ... `Then Sheet1.Range("B1") = "a"`, And nothing happens

Comment: nope, I got it. Managed to adapt it for my purpose. Thanks for your help!